# ¿Cómo puedo recibir la suma de archivos según la id en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy desarrollando un gestor en la nube, resulta que en la dashboard muestro las estadísticas, pero hasta el momento solo he podido realizar un contador el cual recibe todos los archivos que se han subido, pero quisiera que se separé , puesto que debería mostrar es los archivos subidos por usuario, no global mente...

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto o al menos como buscar una guía para solucionar este problema?

```
$count_files = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from file');
```

Imagen de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea seria que cuente los archivos del user_id 1 que serian 5 , y no que termine contando todos..

Comment: Sería algo así: `select COUNT(*) as total from file where user_id=1`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! lee sobre sql.. sobre where y de paso sobre group by, porque tu proxima pregunta es como mostrar la suma de archivos de cada persona, y eso se hace con group by...

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres la lista de archivos subidos por un usuario

```
select * as total from file where user_id = 1
```

Si quieres la lista de usuarios y el número de archivos subidos:

```
select user_id, COUNT(*) as total 
from file 
group by user_id
```

Si quieres la cuenta total de número de archivos subidos

```
select COUNT(*) as total from file
```